# ASP.Net Core 1.1 - Angular2 project CSP not working

Tags: c#, angular, content-security-policy, asp.net-core-1.1

At the moment I'm using NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware nuget package to implement CSP headers. When simply creating a new ASP.NET Core 1.1 MVC Application and modifying the startup as followed, it's still possible to inject a script via the console. What am I missing?

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseCsp(csp =>
        {
            csp.DefaultSources(src => src.Self());
        });
    }
}
```

The intension is to set CSP security to Angular2 generated static files (WebPack). But the CSP does not seem to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Middleware runs from top to bottom, this means that if a middleware exits early, then middlewares that are registered later in the pipeline will not run.

For example, you usually configure the static files middleware before the MVC middleware. That way, the application will *first* attempt to find a static file matching the current request and serve that directly (which will skip MVC). Only when there is no file, it will fall back to the MVC route lookup.

This ultimately means that everything that is there to secure stuff, or to lock users out of completing requests with “real” middleware (those that actually return stuff), has to be registered at the beginning of the pipeline.

In your case, you need to make sure that you call `UseCsp()` *before* `UseMvc` to make sure that the CSP middleware runs before the MVC middleware.